# Depth layering is not showing up on the rendered image in the compositing window

Tags: compositing-nodes, depth-map

Very new to Blender and have been following this tutorial [Create a Realistic Forest in 30 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72LPW4S8bns&t=1272s)

While composting [21:32 in the tutorial], he connects the "Render Layers" depth pin to the "MapValue" value pin. Upon CTRL + SHIFT + LEFT-MOUSE-CLICK and adjusting the Offset/UseMaximum/UseMinimum vaues on the "MapValue" node, he gets a nice stacks of layers.

[image]

I begin off in a similar fashion:

[image]

However, when I try connecting the "Render Layers" and the "MapValue" nodes and attach it to the "Viewer" node, I get a complete black screen. Can any one tell why?

[image]

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out! After you press F12 to render the image, a new window will pop open – “Blender Render”. On that window, go to the last drop-down menu (top right) and you will see three options – “Combined”, “Depth”, “Noisy Image”. Click on “Depth”. Now, you can you back to the Compositing tab and continue with the tutorial starting from 21:32. You should now be able to see stacks of layers representing depth.